# Prove that $x\frac{d}{dx} \delta (x) = -\delta (x)$

Tags: integration, proof-verification, integration-by-parts, kronecker-symbol

Is this proof formal enough? I plan on being a theoretical physicist one day, so I want to get into the good habit of being mathematically strict.

**My proof:**

$u=x$; $du=dx$

$v = \delta (x)$; $dv = -\delta (x)$

$$\int x \frac{d}{dx}(\delta (x))dx = x\delta (x) - \int \delta (x)dx = \int -\delta (x) dx$$

$$x\delta (x) = 0$$

We now integrate both sides in order to properly use the Kronecker delta function.

$$\int x \delta (x) dx = \int 0dx$$

It is known that the $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x)\delta (x)=f(0)$. Thus,

$$0=0$$

---

Comment: Mathematically, the Dirac delta is a distribution (or what physicists call a generalized function), which is meaningful when you pair this with test functions: if $\varphi$ is any smooth compactly supported function, then as **Zachary Selk** computed, we get $$ \langle x \delta'(x), \varphi(x) \rangle = \int x \delta'(x) \varphi(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = -\varphi(0). $$ And we know exactly what distribution gives this result: $-\delta(x)$!

Comment: more explicitly, by definition of the distributional derivative $\langle T',\varphi \rangle = -\langle T,\varphi' \rangle$ and the multiplication of a distribution $T$ by a function $f \in C^\infty$ :  $ \ \ \langle f T,\varphi \rangle = \langle  T,f\varphi \rangle$ we have $\langle x \delta', \varphi \rangle =\langle \delta', x \varphi \rangle =-\langle \delta,  (x\varphi)' \rangle  = -\langle \delta,  \varphi+x \varphi' \rangle =-\langle \delta,  \varphi \rangle$ @SangchulLee

Comment: @user1952009, That's right. In order to be precise, we should work on paring itself and using the definition of derivative of distribution. Thank you for pointing out this.

Comment: @SangchulLee $Generalized\ Functions$ were introduced, in 1935, by the russian Sergei L. Sobolev who WAS a mathematician.

Comment: @FelixMarin Thank you for correcting that! It's interesting to see that the seemingly intuitive term *generalized functions* is less popular in math literature than more ambiguous term *distribution*, which has at least two more independent meanings.

Comment: If the delta function is thought of as the limit of some regular function (e.g., a Gaussian with very small width), then $\delta'(x)$ should be an odd function (see Page 61 of R. Shankar's book: Principles of Quantum Mechanics). So naively we may have $\lim_{x\to 0}x\delta'(x)=0$. How to understand this point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f$ be any smooth compactly supported function. Then:

$$\int x\delta'(x)f(x)\ dx=\int\delta'(x) xf(x)\ dx=-\int\delta(x)(xf'(x)+f(x))\ dx=-0f'(0)-f(0)=-f(0)$$

Comment: In step 3, it looks like you took the derivative of $xf(x)$, took the anti-derivative of $\delta ' (x)$, and then added a negative sign. How is that allowed within the integrand???

Comment: @whatwhatwhat Integration by parts gives that. The intermediate term vanishes because $f$ is compactly supported.

Comment: Why did $f(x)$ need to be introduced?

Comment: @whatwhatwhat What's your definition of $\delta$?

Comment: The one-dimensional Kronecker Delta: $\delta (x) = 0$ when $x \neq 0$ and $\delta (x) = 1$ when $x = 0$

Comment: @whatwhatwhat, the Kronecker delta is meaningfully only under summation: $ \sum_x f(x) \delta(x) = f(0) $. Since integrals are intuitively sums of infinitesimals, say $\sum_i f(x_i) \Delta x_i$, the corresponding version of $\delta$ must be adjusted so that $ \sum_i f(x_i)\delta(x_i) \Delta x_i = f(0)$. In other words, the Dirac delta must compensate the infinitesimal factor $\Delta x$. The issue is that, there is no legitimate function that do this job. So we have to consider a wider class of objects that generalizes functions, and distributions are exactly designed for this purpose.

Comment: @whatwhatwhat no Kronecker delta here, it is the Dirac delta distribution

Comment: [Screenshot from Griffiths, *Introduction to Electrodynamics*](http://imgur.com/a/UkLyE). This is what is confusing me. In the integrand, the author only has $f(x)\delta (x) dx$. Intuitively, I said that the $f(x)$ in the integrand must be my $x$. Yet in the answer above both $x$ and $f(x)$ are present.

Comment: @whatwhatwhat If you can put *any* nice function $f(x)$, why can't you replace this by another nice function $xf(x)$ or something like $x^{2016} + 42f(999x + 1)$?

Comment: nice discussion .. Dirac, Kronecker .. resembles old times philosophycal discussions: would be the case to fix the postulates first ?

Comment: @SangchulLee true, but then that seems rather superfluous, doesn't it? What was wrong with $x$ by itself?

Comment: @whatwhatwhat, Although one conventionally use function notation for the Dirac delta, it is not a function and thus its value at a point is meaningless. So, in general, information on distribution cannot be extracted pointwise by feeding a point as argument. Instead, we can use test functions to extract information. This also means that essentially the only way we manipulate and identify a distribution is to feed them any possible test functions (by the way which we call 'pairing') and see what happens. Zachary Selk's answer demonstrates how this can be done.